# How can i scroll one service section at a time while keeping the .service-inner element in the same place?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I'm trying to create a layout where the user will be able to scroll one service section at a time for ex if the user scrolls down from the first section i want the first section to fade out before the second section fades into the same place as the frist section was

here is a link to js bin Click [here] (https://jsbin.com/xubemivaso/edit?html,js,output)

```
            #one, #two, #three, #four
            {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            height:100%;
            position:absolute;
            display:flex;
            justify-content:center;
            align-items:center;
            font-size:3rem;
            right: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            background-color:black!important;

            }





            #one {
            top:0px;

            }
            #two {
            top:100%;

            }
            #three {
            top:200%;

            }
            #four {
            top:300%;

            }


            .container-outer{
            overflow: hidden;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            position:relative;
            }

            .container-inner{

            overflow:auto;
            position:fixed;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            padding:30px;
            border:30px solid #131313;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            }


            .container-inner::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
            }





        </style>
  </head>
  <body  itemscope itemtype ="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
<div class="cursor"></div>
<div class="cursor"></div>


            <div class="container-outer">
                <div class="container-inner" id="fullpage">



                    <nav>

                        <a class="careers">CAREERS</a>
                        <a class="services">SERVICES</a>

                        <a class="about">ABOUT</a>
                        <a class="find-us">FIND US</a>

                    </nav>


                    <div class="slogan">
                        <h1>SERVICES</h1>
                    </div>





                    <div id="one" class="outer section">


                        <div class="service-inner first">
                            <p class="service-title-first"></p>
                            <p class="service-para-first">
                            Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor Amet Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor Amet   Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor Amet Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor
                            </p>
                            </div>

                    </div>


                    <div id="two" class="outer section">

                        <div class="service-inner second">
                            <p class="service-title-second"></p>
                            <p class="service-para-second">Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor Amet Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor Amet   Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor Amet Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor</p>
                        </div>                  
                    </div>


                    <div id="three" class="outer section">

                        <div class="service-inner third">
                            <p class="service-title-third"></p>
                            <p class="service-para-third">Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor Amet Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor Amet   Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor Amet Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div id="four" class="outer section">

                        <div class="service-inner fourth">
                            <p class="service-title-fourth "></p>
                            <p class="service-para-fourth ">Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor Amet Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor Amet   Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor Amet Lorem Ipsum Sit Dolor</p>
                        </div>                  
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>




        <script>
            (function(container){
            $.fn.stopAtTop= function (serv) {
            var $this = this,
            $container = $(".container-inner"),
            thisPos = $this.offset().top,
            //thisPreservedTop = $this.css("top"),
            setPosition,
            under,
            over;



            under = function(){
            if ($(".container-inner").scrollTop() < thisPos) {



                        TweenMax.to($this, 0, {"position":"absolute","top":""});





            setPosition = over;
        }
    };

    over = function(){
        if (!($(".container-inner").scrollTop() < thisPos) ){

                    TweenMax.to(serv.prev(".service-inner").find('.service-inner'), 1, {"opacity":"0"});                    

                    TweenMax.to($this, 0, {"position":"sticky","top":"0px"});

                    TweenMax.to(serv, 1, {"opacity":"1"});


                    setPosition = under;
                    }
                    };

                    setPosition = over;

                    $container.resize(function()
                    {
                    bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
                    thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
                    setPosition();
                    });

                    $container.scroll(function(){setPosition();});
                    setPosition();
                    };
                    })($(".container-inner"));

                    $('#one').stopAtTop($("#one > .service-inner"));
                    $('#two').stopAtTop($("#two > .service-inner"));
                    $('#three').stopAtTop($("#three > .service-inner"));
                    $('#four').stopAtTop($("#four > .service-inner"));



                </script>
```